# PL/SQL Dynamic SQl

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to run the sql below and retun all the recs with the batchid, declared on top, but i keep getting error, please advice

EXPECTED RESULT:- I need all the batches with the ID declared above, but the dyamanic sql generates for it, how can this sql generate just result for it ???

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LAITEST
IS             
declare
  l_owner varchar2(30) := 'XXFMSLS';
  l_batch varchar2(300) := 'PL_XFER_4';
  l_sql varchar2(32000);
begin
  l_sql := 'select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_CTRL where owner = l_owner and bch_id= l_batch'; 
  dbms_output.put_line( l_sql);
end;
/
```

Comment: And that error is...?

Comment: Are you trying to return the result set from the procedure?

Comment: Error line 5, col 11, ending_line 5, ending col 18, Founf 'varchar2', expecting: ( . @ or % .. :=Default not null or ;)

Comment: you should remove `declare` keyword

Comment: For a start, get rid of the `DECLARE`. It's for anonymous SQL blocks, not for stored procedures. That may get rid of the error, but you're still far away from a working procedure. What do you need the procedure to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) l_owner and l_batch should be dynamically added to the query, the sql sent to the database should have these values substituted.

2) since these are strings, you need to add in the necessary quotes.

3) You don't need `DELCARE`

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LAITEST
  IS             
    l_owner varchar2(30) := 'XXFMSLS';
    l_batch varchar2(300) := 'PL_XFER_4';
    l_sql varchar2(32000);
  begin
    l_sql := 'select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_CTRL where owner = ''' || l_owner || ''' and bch_id= ''' || l_batch || ''''; 
    dbms_output.put_line( l_sql);
  end;
  /    
    set serveroutput on;
    execute    LAITEST;

select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_CTRL where owner = 'XXFMSLS' and bch_id= 'PL_XFER_4'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Also if we want to add multiple sql in the same block can we do that ?

Comment: select * from XXFMSLS.XXFM_FAH_EVNT_STGG_ARCH  where    bch_id in ('SM_1');   select * from XXFMSLS.XXFM_FAH_EVNT_TXNS_HDR where    bch_id in ('SM_1');

Comment: @user803860 - was your comment a question?

Comment: Hey rajesh thanks for the response but I figured out. Thank you

Comment: Rajesh what is wrong in the last query of the block?  I m getting compilation error :- begin   l_sql := 'select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_TXNS_LINE where owner = ''' || l_owner || ''' and sls_evnt_id in (select sls_evnt_id from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_TXNS_HDR where bch_id =''' || l_batch || ''')   select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_TXNS_LINE where owner = ''' || l_owner2 || ''' and event_id in (select sls_evnt_id from '||l_owner ||'.'||XXFM_FAH_EVNT_TXNS_HDR||' where bch_id =''' || l_batch || ''')';   dbms_output.put_line( l_sql);   end; /

Comment: Did you try running the SQL? it gives me an error saying "l_sql not declared". You probably did not copy the "create or replace" section?